# fetch second .then is showing undefined

Tags: reactjs, fetch

onSubmitSignIn = () => {
fetch('http://localhost:3000/signin', {
method: 'post',
mode: 'cors',
headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json' },
body: JSON.stringify({
email: this.state.signInEmail,
password: this.state.signInPassword
})
})
.then(response=> {
console.log("response",response.json());
})
.then(data=>{
console.log("data" ,data);
if(data==='success'){
this.props.onRouteChange('home');
}
})

```
}
```

Comment: please add description to your question

Answer (score 0):

.then(response=> {
return response.json(); })
.then(data=>{ console.log("data" ,data); if(data==='success'){ this.props.onRouteChange('home'); } })

}